# Iterate Through and Rename All Tables w/ Object Qualifiers MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to iterate through all of the tables that begin with a specific prefix to rename them.  The code I've tried is below, but it ends with one of two results, either it crashes SSMS (sometimes), or I get the error message below for each table.  I've tried with and with out `dbo`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or perhaps suggest a better way to do this?

`No item by the name of 'dbo.prefix_TableName' could be found in the current database 'DatabaseName', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.`

Here's the code I'm running...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE [DatabaseName];

DECLARE @oq NVARCHAR(5), @tableName NVARCHAR(128), @newTableName NVARCHAR(128);
SET @oq = N'prefix_';

/*
    find and rename all tables
*/

DECLARE [tableCursor] CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [TABLE_NAME] FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE' AND [TABLE_NAME] LIKE @oq + '%'
    ORDER BY [TABLE_NAME];

OPEN [tableCursor]

FETCH NEXT FROM [tableCursor] INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @newTableName = REPLACE(@tableName, @oq, N'');
    EXEC('EXEC sp_rename ''dbo.' + @tableName + ''', ''' + @newTableName + '''');
END

CLOSE [tableCursor];
DEALLOCATE [tableCursor];
```

Comment: you missed one FETCH statement within the while loop

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel... that was the issue.  You should put that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution without cursors

```
declare @oq nvarchar(max) = N'prefix_'
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
select @cmd = a from (
    select 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''', ''' + REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, @oq, N'') + ''' '
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    for xml path('')
) t(a)
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

In your example nvarchar(5) causes truncation, you probably need nvarchar(7) or nvarchar(max).